# GeoExt2 - Popup Bug?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, geoext, popup

I'm using GeoExt2 (alpha) + Extjs 4.1 now to implement a map application. The thing is sometimes when I select a feature on the map, two popups are displayed. one at the bottom of the screen which has correct info and one empty in the right place. it doesn't go even I close it. I wonder if this is a bug ?

**EDIT**

```
myLayer.events.on({
 featureselected: function(e) {
 createPopup(e.feature);
 },
  featureunselected: function(){
  popup.destroy();
 }
});





function createPopup(feature) {

    popup = Ext.create('GeoExt.Popup', {
    id: 'popup',
        title: title,
        location: feature,
        });


         popup.on({
            close: function() {
                if(OpenLayers.Util.indexOf(myLayer.selectedFeatures,
                                           this.feature) > -1) {
                    selectControl.unselect(this.feature);
                }
            }
        });

    PopupTab = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    id: 'PopupTabs',
        activeTab:2,

    items: [
        { 
            title: 'Supervisor',
            itemId: 'tab1',
        },
        { 
            title: 'student',
            itemId: 'tab2',

            items: [
                { 
                xtype: 'label',
                id: 't',
                html: content,
                layout: 'fit',
                                cls:'tabStyle'
                }
            ]
        },


    ],
    listeners: {
        tabchange: function(panel, tab) {
            if (tab.popup !== undefined) { // show window after tab change
                tab.popup.show();
            }
        }
    }
});

        popup.add(PopupTabs);

        popup.show();

    }
```

Comment: Post your code, otherwise it's impossible to know if it's a GeoExt bug or a mistake in your code.

Comment: Updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the example on the GeoExt2 works, I think the problem is in your code. There are a few things you may try:

- Don't assign an id to the popup, Sencha guys tells that is not a good idea to do that, specially for window container, if you really need a reference to use with the Ext.ComponentQuery use other property instead, like 'name' or 'itemId' or a custom one like 'foo'.
- Check the select control configurations, it may be firing the selection twice.
- set anchorPosition: 'auto'